# Will an Shimano M8000 brake lever blade fit a M8100?

Tags: brakes, shimano

Will an Shimano M8000 brake lever blade fit a M8100? I broke my left blade, it's a Shimano XT M8100. I can only seem to find the replacement M8000 part. I don't want to replace the whole unit, seems like a waste.

Thank you!

EDIT, pics make everything better:

Here's the original **M8100** lever blade:

[image]

and the **M8000** lever blade:

[image]

Comment: By "brake lever part" do you mean the whole brake lever, or only the lever blade (bit of the level you pull with your finger)?

Comment: Just the little bit I put my finger on :) Is there a better term I should use? I'm a noob. Thanks!

Comment: The correct term for that particular part is "lever blade". I'm afraid I don't know if the new one is an exact match or not. They do look similar, I would suggest buying the lever blade from somewhere with a good returns policy, and buy it, compare and return if it won't fit. You can then answer your own question, and other people will know for the future.

Comment: One potential point of issue is that Shimano supposedly tweaked the Servo-Wave curve in the new x100 generation. You may experience slightly different braking feel from the old vs new levers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok this is exciting, I called around locally bikes owned bikes shops and asked if they had some scrap parts laying around. One of them had a Shimano SLX m7000 left brake assembly. I paid for the part and disassembled the lever. It is an *exact* fit. So, you can take a blade from the m7000 hydraulic series and put it on the newest m8100 hydraulic series! Fits like a glove.

KEEP all the parts from the existing brake handle! Use the existing spring, newer pin, newer retention screw, and newer rubber plug/bung!

Reassembling is tricky. I made a temporary paper pin to hold the assembling together. Then I put the assembly into place, then used the real metal pin to push out the paper pin.

Comment: Well done! Maybe if others test with different levers, they can comment on compatibility.

Comment: +1 for keeping the parts... you're on the path to being a bike part hoarder like most of us :))   Well done with your fix.

Comment: interested to hear that this was an exact fit. I have exactly the same problem (broke both lever blades in an otb at the weekend). I have sourced some M8000 lever blades but they're 0.5mm wider. And you had no issue?

Comment: Still running the replacement blade months later.

Answer (score 9):

Hey guys I have found a solution for the shimano xt-m8100 lever blade. I snapped my right lever blade on Christmas day. Was not able to find any lever blade replacement anywhere. Calling local bike shops and the internet. I did finally come across flo motorsports and saw they make an after market lever. The lever is the Flo Motorsports Pro 120 levers. I ordered a set and it came within a week. I was skeptical that these would fit because Shimano perch differ in size. The lever blade from a xt m8000 will not fit in the xt m8100. Installed these today and they fit like a glove. Currently with the pandemic, Shimano parts are far and few. If you snap your lever blade and cannot find a replacement from Shimano these are the way to go.

[image]

Comment: At first glance I thought you were linkspamming motorbike parts, but you're absolutely correct.  A video from manufacturer showing the install process is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDixVFoBRbw
Welcome to Stackexchange !

Comment: @Criggie do you have a link to where these can be purchased?

Comment: These are awesome! Thanks for pointing that out! Absolutely stocked that there are custom levers like this for Shimano :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll attempt a general answer to the question about finding replacement parts from different models of the same Shimano component, but it actually fails in this specific case.

Go to [si.shimano.com](https://si.shimano.com/#/), which is Shimano's center for manuals and technical documents. You can search for the component series, e.g. M8100, and scroll through the components, or there are a number of other search features.

I believe the parts diagrams are marked with the logo `EV`. `DM` stands for dealer manual, and `UM` for user manual. The latter two manuals can be accessed by browsing the regular Shimano site, but the parts diagrams can't be accessed that way. I'm not certain what Shimano's term for this diagram is, and I'm going to call it parts diagram until I learn otherwise.

The diagram for the M8100 brake levers [is here](https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/ev/BL-M8100/EV-BL-M8100-4504.pdf). It calls the lever the LH or RH "lever member unit", and it provides part codes for either one in case you want to try to get one through an LBS. This diagram also gives interchangeability for all parts with the M9100 and M9120 units. Unfortunately, it didn't list backwards compatibility. I've seen Shimano list backwards compatibility on other components, e.g. various R8000 parts diagrams have (I recall) listed compatibility with 6800 components (these are both Ultegra road components, different generations, roughly equivalent to Shimano XT). In any case, A means identical parts, B means interchangeable but the appearance will differ.

The [M8000 parts diagram](https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/ev/BL-M8000/EV-BL-M8000-3853A.pdf), i.e. the one for the previous XT generation, is similarly unhelpful for the OP's case. It lists interchangeability with parts from M9020, M9000, and M785 components.

While this doesn't work for the OP, I'd suggest it as a first step for similar cases. Another thought is that people may sell damaged components for parts on eBay, and it may be possible to determine if the individual part of the component is working. Alternatively, single parts (e.g. a left-hand brake lever or a right-hand one) might get listed because the seller damaged the other side, and decided to just upgrade their bike.

Comment: “EV” most likely stands for exploded view.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the original question is no, like @Jennifer mentioned. M8000 blades are slightly wider (thicker) than M8100. They can, with a bit of force, be inserted in the brake, but there is not proper room left for the spring, so the spring will not function properly.